# Metro Bundler is not compiling React Native App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, metro-bundler

I am totally new to React Native. I have started learning React Native from last two weeks everything was fine and working. But today I got a problem with compilation of my App. As you can see in Picture that it is showing compiling but it will not compile i waited for an hour but nothing was changed.
[Metro Bundle Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DUlt.png)

Comment: I did not changed anything in code. I have same code that was working earlier today but not working now.

Comment: consider share your code

Comment: As I told you I am new to it so kindly guide me which file code you are asking for? App.json or App.js ?